# Incorrect syntax near 'name'-

Tags: database

From this code I get an error in "name,category,price" on "name" like this :

```
create database coffee
create table items(
iid int identity(1,1) primary key,
name varchar(250) not null,
category varchar(250) not null,
price bigint not null
);
name,category,price 
select * from items
```

Help please

Comment: What database platform are you using?

Comment: `name,category,price 
select * from items` Please explain what `name,category,price` is doing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is:

```
select name,category,price  from items
```

This is due to you wanting to select those 3 values from the database.

Whereas

```
name,category,price /*Not sure what this does */
select * from items /* This means select all columns from the table */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'm new to databases that's why, again thanks.

Comment: Can you mark as answered if this works? I'd love the stack overflow cred

Comment: Sure, I just need to wait 4 mins to do that because I just created an account in stackoverflow

Comment: There you go @StarshipladDev ,Thanks